# Next.js getServerSideProps props undefined when retry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The current situation is that I'm sending an axios request in getServerSideProps, and exposing the value through props via SSR to the client. However, I need to send a token in the header, so I'm using an instance. If the token expires, I use refreshToken to reissue it, and if refreshToken also expires, it generates an error.

Currently, the retry works fine and the token is also reissued properly. Moreover, the axios request in getServerSideProps is also working properly, and console.log(serviceList) is outputting properly. However, the issue is that when I retry due to token expiration, return { props: { serviceList } } returns undefined as props, whereas it works fine under normal circumstances. Strangely, the console.log(serviceList) above it is outputting properly, but the serviceList in the client is returning undefined.

I've been struggling with this problem for more than two days, but I haven't been able to solve it. Please let me know what the problem is.

Thank you always.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import AdmLayout from "/components/adm/AdmLayout";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { createServerSideAxiosInstance, getSearch } from "/public/assets/js/common";
import store from "/store";

const Service = ({ pageProps: { serviceList } }) => {
  console.log("serviceList in Page", serviceList);
  return (
    <AdmLayout>
        <p>
          {serviceList &&
            serviceList.map((v, i) => (
              <span
                style={{ padding: "0 10px", display: "inlineBlock" }}
                key={i}
              >
                {i}
              </span>
            ))}
        </p>
    </AdmLayout>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  try {
    const serverSideAxiosInstance = await createServerSideAxiosInstance(
      context,
      store
    );
    const {
      data: { result: serviceList },
    } = await serverSideAxiosInstance.get("/api/v1/admin/service/0");
    console.log(serviceList)
    return {
      props: {
        serviceList,
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response);
    if (err.response.status && err.response.status === 403) {
      // context.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/adm/login" });
      // context.res.end();
    } else {
      console.log(err.response.data.code);
      // context.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/adm/login" });
      // context.res.end();
    }
    return {
      props: {
        serviceList: [],
      },
    };
  }
}

export default Service;
```

```
export async function createServerSideAxiosInstance(context, store) {
  let isRetryRequest = false;
  let newTokenForRetry = "";
  const cookies = cookie.parse(context.req.headers.cookie || "");
  const serverSideAxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST,
  });

  serverSideAxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      const userState = JSON.parse(cookies.userState);
      const userInfo = userState.userInfo;

      if (isRetryRequest) {
        config.headers.Authorization = newTokenForRetry;
        isRetryRequest = false;
      } else {
        config.headers.Authorization = cookies.token || "noUser";
      }
      console.log(
        new Date().getHours() +
          ":" +
          new Date().getMinutes() +
          ":" +
          new Date().getSeconds()
      );
      config.data = {
        ...config.data,
        login_id: userInfo.login_id ?? "noUser@noUser.com",
        mem_no: userInfo.mem_no ?? 0,
      };
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  serverSideAxiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    async (error) => {
      const originalRequest = error.config;
      console.log("err.response.data", error.response.data);
      if (error.response.data.code === 609 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        const cookies = cookie.parse(context.req.headers.cookie || "");
        const refreshToken = cookies.rfToken;
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        try {
          const { headers } = await axios.post(
            "https://myDomain/refresh",
            {
              refreshToken,
            },
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
              },
            }
          );
          const newToken = headers.authorization;
          const newRfToken = headers.refreshtoken;
          const mem_type = headers.mem_type;
          const cookieHeader = saveToken(
            newToken,
            newRfToken,
            mem_type,
            context.res
          );
          cookies.newToken = newToken;
          newTokenForRetry = newToken;
          isRetryRequest = true;
          return await serverSideAxiosInstance(originalRequest);
        } catch (err) {
          const res = err.response;
          console.log("res.data", res.data);
          if (res.data.code === 403) {
            store.dispatch(returnUserState());
            if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
              Router.push("/");
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }

          if (res.data.code === 609) {
            deleteToken(context.res);
            store.dispatch(returnUserState());
          } else if (res.data.code === 611) {
            deleteToken(context.res);
            store.dispatch(returnUserState());
            //       window.location.href = "/";
            return Promise.reject(error);
          } else {
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
        }
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
  );

  return serverSideAxiosInstance;
}
```

I hope that the props will be outputted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this and you will always get the serviceList props.

```
const Service = (props) => {
  const { serviceList } = props;
  console.log("serviceList in Page", serviceList);
  return (
    <AdmLayout>
      <p>
        {serviceList &&
          serviceList.map((v, i) => (
            <span style={{ padding: "0 10px", display: "inlineBlock" }} key={i}>
              {i}
            </span>
          ))}
      </p>
    </AdmLayout>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let serviceList = [];
  try {
    const serverSideAxiosInstance = await createServerSideAxiosInstance(context, store);

    const { data } = await serverSideAxiosInstance.get("/api/v1/admin/service/0");
    serviceList = data.result;
    console.log(serviceList);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response);
    if (err.response.status && err.response.status === 403) {
      // context.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/adm/login" });
      // context.res.end();
    } else {
      console.log(err.response.data.code);
      // context.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/adm/login" });
      // context.res.end();
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { serviceList },
  };
}
```